# error 'The given key was not present in the dictionary' when trying to API HTTP request token with Blue Prism

Tags: vb.net, api, http, blueprism

Im trying to use the Blue Prism object HTTP request to get an access token for further processing the items. However, i couldn't manage to get the token due to the error 'The given key was not present in the dictionary'. I have looked all parameters and still didn't manage to solve the issue. I use a built in visual basic code to get the result as a collection which is later parsed to JSON to get the token.

The underlying visual basic code is:

```vb
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(addressURL)

    If forcePreAuth Then
       'Sometimes a web server will require the authorisation header in the initial request
       'In which case we have to add the basic authorization header manually.
       Dim bytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}",username,password))
       Dim base64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
       request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " & base64)
    Else
      If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(password) Then
        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username,password)
      End If
    End If

    If useProxy Then
        Dim proxyURI As New Uri(proxyURL)
        Dim proxy As New WebProxy(proxyURI, True)
        Dim proxyCred As New NetworkCredential(proxyUsername, proxyPassword)
        Dim credCache As New CredentialCache()
        credCache.Add(proxyURI, "Basic", proxyCred)
        proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        proxy.Credentials = credCache
        request.Proxy = proxy
    End If

    request.Method = method
    request.ContentType = contentType

    Dim httpRequest As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(request, HttpWebRequest)
    If httpRequest IsNot Nothing Then
      If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(accept) Then
        httpRequest.Accept = accept
      End If
      If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(certID) Then
        httpRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(m_Certificates(certID))
      End If
    End If

    For Each r As DataRow In headers.Rows
        For Each c As DataColumn In headers.Columns
            Dim columnName As String = c.ColumnName
            Dim val As String = r(columnName).ToString
            request.Headers.Add(columnName,val)
        Next
        Exit For 'Only one row is allowed
    Next

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(body) Then
      Dim requestStream As IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
      Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(requestStream, New Text.UTF8Encoding(False))
        sw.Write(body)
      End Using
    End If

    Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
      Dim responseStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
      Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(responseStream)
      resultData = sr.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
```

Screenshots:
Input parameter
[image: Input parameter]

Input parameter request token
[image: Input parameter request token]

Request token:
[image: screenshot request token]

Output parameter:
[image: Output parameter]

Comment: Since i have only 1 collection which i use in the code (i.e. Headers) and the error is is that it couldn't find the key in the dictionary, i think that the issue might be on the variable Headers but im not sure.

Comment: What version of Blue Prism is this?

Comment: Would you mind also providing a screenshot of your process-level diagram?

Comment: @esqew: im using version 5.0.24. In fact the issue mentioned above is the first action in the process diagram in order to get the token. The second action is to parse JSON to collection. Thus, it does not pass the first action. See above for the screenshots.

Comment: What I'm trying to get an understanding of more specifically is, where exactly have you sourced the value for "Certificate ID" (that you've redacted in your screenshot)?

Comment: I give in the Certificate ID as an input parameter of which the value i received from the clerk managing the api's from the organization in Postman. Certificate ID = Client ID in Postman ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blue Prism uses a bit of a peculiar pattern regarding Certificates. The way the `Utility - HTTP` object is designed is to allow for the loading of certificate files (`.cer`, etc) on-the-fly into a local Certificate Store, which assigns a new `Certificate ID` each time.

Before firing your `HTTP Request`, use the `Load Certificate` action within the same `Utility - HTTP` object to output a valid `Certificate ID`, which you can then pass to `HTTP Request`'s `Certificate ID` parameter.

Comment: Or you could just write your own code stage to do this :). I wrote a code stage to be able to use multi cert file with HTTP request. Seems to work without any issues